# How to increment value in dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have these lines inside text file:

```
2018-11-06 16:52:01.901| on thread[140447603222272 c0s0]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| omer| (stmt : 0) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:52:15.160| on thread[140447603222272 c0s1]| IP[192.168.0.244:5001]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 1) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:52:27.351| on thread[140447603222272 c0s3]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 3) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:52:28.159| on thread[140447603222272 c0s5]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 5) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:52:30.485| on thread[140447603222272 c0s7]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 7) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:52:54.217| on thread[140447603222272 c0s11]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| Gilc| (stmt : 11) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:53:04.600| on thread[140447603222272 c10s12]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 12) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:53:05.617| on thread[140447603222272 c10s13]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 13) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:53:18.958| on thread[140447603222272 c10s14]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 14) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:53:26.25| on thread[140447603222272 c10s15]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| Guy| (stmt : 15) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:53:36.816| on thread[140447603222272 c10s17]| IP[192.168.0.244:5005]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 17) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:53:41.116| on thread[140447603222272 c13s18]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 18) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:53:51.517| on thread[140447603222272 c13s19]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 19) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:53:55.500| on thread[140447603222272 c13s21]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 21) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:53:56.333| on thread[140447603222272 c13s23]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master_backup| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 23) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:54:03.758| on thread[140447603222272 c13s25]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 25) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:54:07.891| on thread[140447603222272 c13s26]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 26) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:54:22.66| on thread[140447603222272 c20s27]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| ben| (stmt : 27) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:54:27.849| on thread[140447603222272 c20s28]| IP[192.168.0.216:5000]| master_tati| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 28) | admin|  Success
2018-11-06 16:54:36.533| on thread[140447603222272 c22s29]| IP[192.168.0.244:5000]| master| 192.168.0.244| userAdmin| (stmt : 29) | admin|  Success
```

I want to count for each user how many lines he got for example I want to get this dictionary for user 'userAdmin' -> `dict = {'userAdmin : 16}` because there are 16 lines with 'userAdmin'

I have implemented the following code:

```
def parse_log_file(log_file):
    print(len(""))
    my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(my_path, log_file)
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[1:]
        map = {}
        for line in lines:
            elements = line.strip().lstrip().split('|')
            if elements[8].lstrip() == 'Success':
                map[elements[5].lstrip()] = 1
                if map[elements[5].lstrip()] is not None:
                    map[elements[5].lstrip()] += 1
                # map[elements[5]] = elements[8]

        for k, v in map.items():
            print(k, ':', v)
```

But this is what I got which is wrong:

```
omer : 2
userAdmin: 2
Gilc : 2
Guy : 2
ben : 2
```

i would expect userAdmin to be 16 and not 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Improvements that can be made:**

- Check for existence of key in dict before assigning, if the key exists, increment the value
- Reduce over-use of `lstrip` and `rstrip`, `strip` does both these at once
- You are advised to change the name of our dictionary from `map`. That is a python Keyword.

Revised solution:

```
def parse_log_file(log_file):
    print(len(""))
    my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(my_path, log_file)
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[1:]
        mapping = {}
        for line in lines:
            elements = line.split('|')
            # strip the lines of surrounding spaces
            elements = [t.strip() for t in elements]
            if elements[8].lstrip() == 'Success':
                # check if the key already exists in the dict
                # create key if not exists
                if not mapping.get(elements[5]):
                    mapping[elements[5]] = 1
                else:
                    # increment the value if key exists
                    mapping[elements[5]] += 1

        for k, v in mapping.items():
            print(k, ':', v)
```

This produces:

```
userAdmin : 16
Gilc : 1
Guy : 1
ben : 1
```

Comment: While this code works, it's inefficient due to the code having to call the dictionary for it's key twice for each loop every time. Once because of the if-statement, and once to either write to the already existing key of the dict, or when creating a new key inside of the dictionary. That will not scale well once the number of keys increase. Using [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl) is valid code for python, and in the small scale, might sometimes be more readable. However, actually doing what you're trying to do, and then catching the exception will always be faster.

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the entry inside of your dictionary inside if your for-loop.

Try this instead:

```
def parse_log_file(log_file):
    my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(my_path, log_file)
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()[1:]
        d = {}
        for line in lines:
            elements = line.strip().lstrip().split('|')
            if elements[8].lstrip() == 'Success':
                try:
                    d[elements[5].lstrip()] += 1
                except KeyError:
                    d[elements[5].lstrip()] = 1

        for k, v in d.items():
            print(k, ':', v)
```

I've changed your dictionary from `map` to `d` because `map` is a built-in function, and you should avoid overwriting those, because they can create bugs that are hard to track down.

The output of the above code is:

```
userAdmin : 16
Gilc : 1
Guy : 1
ben : 1
```

What's happening here is that we're using [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) logic to try to do `+1` to the variable inside of the dictionary. If that fails, we catch the `KeyError` and then just create a new entry inside of the dictionary.

Comment: In the output, Where is user `omer`?

Comment: @simic0de It's skipped because of `lines = f.readlines()[1:]`.

Answer (score 1):

For every success line, you change the count back to 1 in the line `map[elements[5].lstrip()] = 1`.

Instead you would like to initialize the counter to 1 for the first line the user appears, and for the next times just increment the counter by 1.

You can change the logic to the following:

```
name = elements[5].lstrip()
if name in d.keys():
    d[name] += 1
else:
    d[name] = 1
```